# A Sql statement gets different results on Maria DB and Mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Table structures is:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| column_name   | is_nullable | column_default | data_type | character_maximum_length |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id            | NO          | NULL           | int       |                     NULL |
| name          | NO          | NULL           | varchar   |                      100 |
| last_start    | YES         | NULL           | datetime  |                     NULL |
| y             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        4 |
| m             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        2 |
| d             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        2 |
| h             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        2 |
| i             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        2 |
| s             | YES         | NULL           | varchar   |                        2 |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

Data in Table is:

```
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | name                    | last_start          | y    | m    | d    | h    | i    | s    |
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 55 | daemon_service_service  | 2019-08-21 11:05:59 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 56 | daemon_ohrclean_service | 2019-08-21 10:47:59 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 05   | 00   | 00   |
| 57 | daemon_mqclean_service  | 2019-08-21 10:47:59 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 58 | daemon_loggrab_service  | 2019-08-21 10:59:59 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 59 | daemon_test1            | 2019-08-20 12:26:31 | NULL | NULL | 20   | 11   | 25   | 30   |
| 60 | daemon_test2            | 2019-08-20 12:26:31 | NULL | NULL | 20   | 11   | 25   | 30   |
| 61 | daemon_test3            | 2019-08-20 12:26:31 | NULL | NULL | 20   | 11   | 25   | NULL |
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

SQL statement is:

```
SELECT t.*, concat(ifnull(`y`,date_format(now(),'%Y')),'-',
                   ifnull(`m`,date_format(now(),'%m')),'-',
                   ifnull(`d`,date_format(now(),'%d')),' ',
                   ifnull(`h`,date_format(now(),'%H')),':',
                   ifnull(`i`,date_format(now(),'%i')),':',`s`)
FROM `daemon_service`  t 
where 
`s` is not null and 
last_start< concat(ifnull(`y`,date_format(now(),'%Y')),'-',
                   ifnull(`m`,date_format(now(),'%m')),'-',
                   ifnull(`d`,date_format(now(),'%d')),' ',
                   ifnull(`h`,date_format(now(),'%H')),':',
                   ifnull(`i`,date_format(now(),'%i')),':',`s`)
```

I have two sql environment, one is `MariaDB 10.3.15`, other one is `Mysql 5.7.24`.

when I run the sql above on `MariaDB 10.3.15`,The result returns is correct, which is nothing.

But When I run the sql on `Mysql 5.7.24`, it returns  **id 59 and 60**, which is not correct.

Here are the result:

```
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | name                    | last_start          | y    | m    | d    | h    | i    | s    | concat(ifnull(`y`...|
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
| 59 | daemon_test1            | 2019-08-20 12:26:31 | NULL | NULL | 20   | 11   | 25   | 30   | 2019-08-20 11:25:30 |
| 60 | daemon_test2            | 2019-08-20 12:26:31 | NULL | NULL | 20   | 11   | 25   | 30   | 2019-08-20 11:25:30 |
+----+-------------------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
```

My question is:

1. What cause this problem?
2. How to make it correct on `Mysql 5.7.24`?

Comment: What was the value of now() when you ran this? returning 59 and 60 when now() = 2019-08-21 10:58:25 is correct..

Comment: MySQL seems to be doing it wrong.

Comment: @P.Salmon it should not return any rows regardless of the value of now. `2019-08-20 12:26:31` is greater than `2019-08-20 11:25:30`

Comment: @salman ?? I must be missing something, today us 2018-08-21 (at least in my region)

Comment: @P.Salmon the `d` column contains 20, so it'll use this value instead of 21 returned by now. It is a bug in MySQL 5.x; the same query produces 0 rows in MySQL 8 on same date.

Comment: Because of the screwball time calculation, any difference in `NOW()` will lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: @RickJames Actually the result has nothing to do with `NOW()`，as long as your year is 2019 and your month is 08